# PHP variable inside onclick function?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP file. In this I have to write html. Also instead of closing PHP tag every time, I just use `echo 'html code';`

So my code is like:

```
<?php    
$mid = 1;    
echo '<div class="message_wrap"><span onclick="viewMessage(1)">Click</span></div>';    
?>

<script>
function viewMessage(id){
    alert(id);
    
}    
</script>
```

It gives me 1 in alert but I want to use `$mid` in `onclick function` but it breaks my code. I used this:

```
  echo '<div class="message_wrap"><span onclick="viewMessage("'.$mid.'")">Click</span></div>';
```

but I got nothing on clicking and when I see generated HTML it is breaking like this

`<div class="message_wrap"> <span 1")"="" onclick="viewMessage(">Click</span> </div>`;

```
<?php
$mid = 1;
?>
<div class="message_wrap"><span onclick="viewMessage(<?php echo $mid;?>)">Click</span></div>
```

But I don't want to close and open PHP tag as I have large code, so it does not look good.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: its just a broken quote, just remove the quotes in `("'.$mid.'")` if you're expecting a number

Comment: I got nothing on clicking and when i see generated html it is breaking like this `<div class="message_wrap">
<span 1")"="" onclick="viewMessage(">Click</span>
</div>`;

Comment: Is the second approach working? Even if the code may not look so good, it's the better convention and you should stick to the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" error because the parameter you passed has space before it and "="" after ) because of that approach

to fix it change your

```
echo '<div class="message_wrap"><span onclick="viewMessage("'.$mid.'")">Click</span></div>';
```

to

```
echo '<div class="message_wrap"><span onclick="viewMessage(\''.$mid.'\')">Click</span></div>';
```